# Quantifying Static Electricity Hazard with High Explosives

Tags: electrical-engineering, materials, design, electromagnetism, electrical

In the making of firework explosives, the explosive mixtures are handled with great care to avoid static electricity induced detonation of the explosives. Is it a good idea that they store the explosives in a plastic container - isn't there a risk of static buildup that could detonate the explosives?

- [How It's Made Fireworks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3mlrjrLUpyg)

Comment: Would the storage in plastic containers be necessary to control the moisture content or should they go back to leather coated in pig fat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Static electricity is a major issue when handling or dealing with explosives.

When blast holes are loaded with ANFO (ammonium nitrate fuel oil) as the main explosive, and a specific density of ANFO is required in the holes, the ANFO is blown into the holes via compressed air and a tube.

For short holes drilled with hand held machines, the tube is made of aluminum because of static electricity concerns. For large holes drilled with larger machines, the tube is made of plastic. To ensure that static electricity will not be an issue low static plastic tubing is used.

Generally black plastic tubing is used. To differentiate low static tubing for conventional tubing, low static tubing has a red or orange stripe that runs the full length of tubing.

Providing the plastic containers used to store high explosives are made of low static plastic, static electricity will not be an issue. However, the plastic containers need to be identifiable as being made from low static plastic.